# general solution to system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

hello I am give the following equation to solve:

$t\frac {dX} {dt}$= $\bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 3 & -2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr]X(t)$+$\bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1-t^2 \\ 2t \end{smallmatrix} \bigr]$

with the hint: In the homogeneous equation $[t\frac {d} {dt}-A]X(t)=0$, let $X(t)=t^{\lambda}W$, where $W$ is a constant vector. This substitution is motivated by the fact that $t\frac {dX} {dt}-AX=0$ has the appearance of an Euler-Cauchy equation.

My approach:
As mentioned in the hint, I tried to find $X(t)=t^{\lambda}W$, from this equation I got that $\lambda= A =$ $\bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 3 & -2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr]$. In attempt to find $ t^{A}$, I tried to turn it into exponential matrix form turning it into $e^{Alnt}$. Form here I can't seem to find the exponential matrix, and now I am stuck with this question. Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misinterpreting the hint.  Let's set $X(t)=t^\lambda \vec w$, and plug this into the homogeneous equation.  If you do this and simplify, you should get $$\lambda t^\lambda \vec w = At^\lambda\vec w.$$  To make this a bit more suggestive, let's substitute $X(t)=t^\lambda \vec w$ back in.  The above becomes $\lambda X=AX,$ where I have hidden the dependence on $t$.  Remember that $X$ is a vector...  What does this mean?  What would you call a vector $X$ and a scalar $\lambda$ with the property that $\lambda X=AX$, if $A$ is a square matrix?

Comment: well this means that $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of of square matrix A. So this would mean that $t^{-1}$ and $t^{1}$ would be the solution to the homogeneous equation of X, from here I would need to find the particular solution to the nonhomogenous equation, to get the general solution. Is my approach correct? Thank you for the help by the way. :)

Comment: That's definitely part of it, yes.  Your eigenvalues are correct; but what does the vector $\vec w$ in the candidate solution $X(t)=t^\lambda\vec w$ represent?  Hint: $X(t)$ should satisfy $AX(t)=\lambda X(t)$ for any value of $t$.

EDIT: As for the general solution...  You will get two solutions of the homogeneous equation from the above analysis; let's call them $X_1$ and $X_2$.  These each satisfy the the differential equation $$t\frac{dX}{dt}=AX(t)+[1-t^2,2t]^T$$.  However, this is not yet in the form $$\frac{dX}{dt}=A(t)X(t)+f(t)$$.

Comment: (Continued) ...where $A(t)$ is a matrix function and $f(t)$ is a vector function.  The second equation is the one in which the usual methods of solution are applicable.  For example, variation of parameters.  As such, you will have to change it into this form before you can find the general solution of the inhomogeneous equation.  Thankfully, the above two equations are obviously related...